# WinDbg and SOS: get method return type

Tags: .net, windbg, sos

In WinDBG with SOS loaded you can see methods and their arguments via `!dumpmt`, e.g.

```
!dumpmt -md 00007ffb1c0506f8

...
00007ffb1c529ae0 00007ffb1c1a4c38 PreJIT System.String.Concat(System.String, System.String)
00007ffb1c568910 00007ffb1c1a4c48 PreJIT System.String.Concat(System.String, System.String, System.String)
00007ffb1c566ab0 00007ffb1c1a4c58 PreJIT System.String.Concat(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)
...
```

Without opening `ildasm` or `ILspy` (or any other disassembler): how do you view the *return* types of methods (be it `void` or an actual type)?

Comment: I never needed that information in many years of using WinDbg and .NET, but it's a nice question, IMHO. What do you need that info for?

Comment: Couldn't figure it out, neither with SOS nor with netext. I [opened issue 21](https://github.com/rodneyviana/netext/issues/21) in the netext project.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: honestly i was deep into debugging some very obscure code and i kept going back and forth between ildasm and windbg and i thought there must be a way, but coudln't find anything. And old old post from MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/may/net-framework-internals-how-the-clr-creates-runtime-objects  (figure 11) mentions "return type" but that is not the output i ever saw.

Comment: Okay, that information is *very* old. It's relevant for .NET Framework 1.1 somewhen around 2003. That predates my knowledge. I started debugging .NET in 2008 or so.